# Counting number of unique adjacent pairs of same elements in an array

Tags: java, arrays

My function does not return the correct answer. My task is to count the two numbers in an array that are the same and next to each other here is a sample:

```
array_1 = {1,2,2,3,4,4,2};   ans = 2
array_2 = {2,2,3,4,4};       ans = 2
array_3 = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1};   ans = 1
array_4 = {1,2,3,4,2};       ans = 0
```

Here is my function. Observed output is given as comments.

```
public class countClampsTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int array_1[] = {1,2,2,3,4,4,2}; // expected result: 2
        int array_2[] = {2,2,3,4,4};     // expected result: 2
        int array_3[] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1}; // expected result: 1
        int array_4[] = {1,2,3,4,2};     // expected result: 0

        System.out.println(countClamps(array_1)); // Returns 2
        System.out.println(countClamps(array_2)); // Returns 1
        System.out.println(countClamps(array_3)); // Returns 1
        System.out.println(countClamps(array_4)); // Returns 0
    }

    static int countClamps(int[] arr) {
        int result = 0;
        int nextNext = 0;
        for (int current = 0; current < arr.length - 1; current++) {
            for (int next = current; next <= current + 1; next++) {
                nextNext = next  + 1;
                if(nextNext >= arr.length) {
                    nextNext = arr.length -1;
                }
                if (arr[current] == arr[next] && current != next) {
                    if(arr[next] != arr[nextNext]) {
                        result++;   
                    } else if(arr[next] == arr[nextNext] && arr.length % 2 == 0) {
                        result = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is the answer 3 for array 1? There are just two pairs of numbers next to each other? You might need to explain this a bit more...

Comment: Your task description is unclear. Why is first answer supposed to be 3? I see two pairs of number "that are the same and next to each other", i.e. `2,2` and `4,4`, so how is that an answer of 3?

Comment: Thank you @BretC it should be 2 edited it for correction

Comment: Why do you need nested loop for this logic? Re-think what you need to do, because you should only have one loop.

Comment: Why do you have a loop (the inner one) that counts from `current` to `current`?  Why does `arr.length % 2` factor into finding a pair?

Comment: What should the result be for `[1,1,2,2,1,1]`?

Comment: When I run the program, I get 2 1 0 0 (not 2 1 1 0). Did our edit cause harm??

Comment: @ScottHunter that should probably 3

Comment: @OleV.V. Thank you for the correction what you said is correct

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you want to count runs of at least 2 equal numbers in a row?

Comment: I think your problem is with the `nextNext >= arr.length` case — the case where the equal numbers are in the end of the array. In this case you can ignore `nextNext` completely, and subtracting 1 to get it inside the array is the wrong solution because it causes `arr[next] != arr[nextNext]` to be false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few issues in your code.

In the test:

```
            if (arr[current] == arr[next] && current != next) {
```

you compare current with next; you could obtain the same result by starting the next loop at current+1 instead of current:

```
        for (int next = current+1; next <= current + 1; next++) {
            nextNext = next  + 1;
            ...
            if (arr[current] == arr[next]) {
               ...
            }
        }
```

which makes the loop redundant: it's only executed once, so the code above is equivalent to:

```
            int next = current+1;
            nextNext = next  + 1;
            ...
            if (arr[current] == arr[next]) {
               ...
            }
```

Now in your inner test:

```
                if(arr[next] != arr[nextNext]) {
                    result++;   
                } else if(arr[next] == arr[nextNext] && arr.length % 2 == 0) {
                    result = 1;
                }
```

You can see that the first part of the second condition is always true, so it's equivalent to:

```
                if(arr[next] != arr[nextNext]) {
                    result++;   
                } else if(arr.length % 2 == 0) {
                    result = 1;
                }
```

The remaining condition means that you reset result to 1 if the array has an even number of elements (why?).

at the end of the array, result will not be incremented if the last two elements are equal, which is why you don't get the correct result in the second case.

Here is my solution:

```
static int countClamps(int[] arr) {
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        if (arr[i] == arr[i-1]
                && (i == arr.length-1 || arr[i] != arr[i+1])) {
            ++result;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You already solved my issue with regards to my logic solution! Thank you for the explanation! One question why does your code does not encounter the index out of bounds for arr[i+1]?

Comment: This is because of the shortcut evaluation of `||`. When `i` is at the last index, `i == arr.length-1` is true so Java already knows that the whole of `i == arr.length-1 || arr[i] != arr[i+1]` will be true and in this case doesn’t look into the second part of the expression, hence never gets to trying `arr[i+1]`.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is: Stop you loop still one iteration earlier: use `current < arr.length - 2` (this will cause `nextNext` to be within the array always). After your outer loop, just compare the last two elements of the array. If they are equal, add 1 to result. Done.

Except if the array has length 0 or 1, you will need to treat that specially.

Comment: I will try to translate your solution into code thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I've added an extra boolean to keep track of already counted duplicates after each other.

```
static int countClamps(int[] arr) {
    int result = 0;
    int prev = 0;
    boolean same = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            prev = arr[i];
        } else {
            if (arr[i] == prev) {
                if (!same) {
                    result++;
                    same = true;
                }
            } else {
                prev = arr[i];
                same = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Nice code. However, I think the OP would be helped better if you left to him or her to write the code. A more helpful answer may spot errors/issues in the original code and/or sketch a better algorithm.

Comment: I will take note of this but I will try to create a similar solution patterned on your code, thank you!

Comment: This is another great solution!

Answer (score 0):

Once you've found a pair skip an index in loop.

```
    public static int pairs(int[] list){
      int pairs = 0;
      for(int x = 1; x < list.length; x++){
        if(list[x] == list[x-1]){
          pairs++;
          x=x+1;}
      }
      return pairs;
    }
```